# External user cannot create a new folder under Documents page in the shared SharePoint Online site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

How to enable the external user to create a new folder under Documents page?

**The external user is able to open and edit existing folders and files under Documents, but cannot create a new folder.**

below is the error info when creating a new folder:
[image]
[image]

Below are the customized permission levels of the site for the external user:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, I can reproduce your issue with the same customized permission levels. Below is my find:

I give the user in the organization this permission level, he could create the folder. However it's not work for external user. It's weird.

Then I give the external user contribute permission level, he could create the folder in the library. So I guess you need to give external user contribute permissions to create a folder in the library.

Comment: Hi Michael, yes, it is odd (is it a SharePoint bug? could you report this to MS internally?). I made some further test and found as long as the option "Use Remote Interfaces  -  Use SOAP, ..." being ticked, the external user would be able to create new folders. But this introduced a new issue, the external user could open the "Site contents" page which is not preferred for my customized permission. Also your suggested contribute permission scope includes delete permission which is not intended either for the customized permission. Thanks